# How do I show my data via a loop outside of a StreamReader

Tags: c#, streamreader

So I am trying display my data from a StreamReader outside of the using portion.  I am able to display it all INSIDE of the StreamReader however showing it OUTSIDE of the StreamReader is proving more complicated.

I understand that my while loop inside the StreamReader will show all the data I need (and it is).  But I need it to show from the for loop that I have at the bottom. (While loop was left in just as a reference).

When I run it through the for loop I either get 
"end 
end
end 
end" 
or 
"end 
of 
record 
indicator"

I get the "Ends" when i use the array index number in the for loop, and the "end of record indicator" when i use the "i".

How can I get it to display what my while loop is displaying?

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] lineOutVar;
          using (StreamReader readerOne = new StreamReader("../../FileIOExtraFiles/DataFieldsLayout.txt"))
            {
                string lineReader = readerOne.ReadLine();
                string[] lineOutput = lineReader.Split('\n');
            lineOutVar = lineOutput;



            while (readerOne.EndOfStream == false)
            {
                lineOutVar = readerOne.ReadLine().Split();
                Console.WriteLine(lineOutVar[0]);
            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < lineOutVar.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lineOutVar[0]);
        }
```

Comment: Capture it into a variable, so it's available to you after the stream is closed.

Comment: Thats what the lineOutVar is for.  I call it before the StreamReader starts, throw it into the StreamReader and have it equal my lineOutPut var, and then recall it outside the StreamReader.  But for some reason thats only giving me the 4 indexes for the data.  Unless I'm misunderstanding what your saying.

Comment: An array may not be the right container since it's size needs to be declared ahead of time. And it looks like you're just assigning it to a single split line over and over, rather than assigning each line to a unique index in the array. You might consider a list instead. Also look into `File.ReadAllLines` instead of the `StreamReader` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Use List class.

```
    List<string> lineOutVar = new List<string>();
    using (System.IO.StreamReader readerOne = new System.IO.StreamReader("../../FileIOExtraFiles/DataFieldsLayout.txt"))
    {
        while(readerOne.EndOfStream == false)
        {
            string lineReader = readerOne.ReadLine();
            lineOutVar.Add(lineReader); //add the line to the list of string
        }
    }

    foreach(string line in lineOutVar) //loop through each of the line in the list of string
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the content:

```
string[] lineOutVar;
 List<string[]> lst_lineOutVar = new List<string[]>();
 using (StreamReader readerOne = new StreamReader("E:\\TEST\\sample.txt"))
 {
       string lineReader = readerOne.ReadLine();
       string[] lineOutput = lineReader.Split('\n');
       lineOutVar = lineOutput;



       while (readerOne.EndOfStream == false)
        {
                    lineOutVar = new string[1];
                    lineOutVar = readerOne.ReadLine().Split();

                    lst_lineOutVar.Add(lineOutVar);

                    //Console.WriteLine(lineOutVar[0]);
                }

                String getcontent = string.Empty;
                foreach (var getLst in lst_lineOutVar)
                {
                    getcontent = getcontent + "," + getLst[0].ToString();
                }


                Console.WriteLine(getcontent);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just skip the StreamReader and use `File.ReadAllLines`:

```
string[] lineOutVar = File.ReadAllLines("../../FileIOExtraFiles/DataFieldsLayout.txt");
```

Now you have an array of the file lines, and you can loop over them and split them however you like.